# Check if there's something "waiting for" the return value of a function

Tags: python

I'm wondering if anyone can think up a way to check if a function needs to return a meaningful value in Python. That is, to check *whether the return value will be used for anything*. I'm guessing the answer is no, and it is better to restructure my program flow. The function in question pulls its return values from a network socket. If the return value is not going to get used, I don't want to waste the resources fetching the result.

I tried already to use tracebacks to discover the calling line, but that didn't work. Here's an example of what I had in mind:

```
>>> def func():
...  print should_return()
...
>>> func()
False
>>> ret = func()
True
```

The function "knows" that its return value is being assigned.

Here is my current workaround:

```
>>> def func(**kwargs):
...   should_return = kwargs.pop('_wait', False)
...   print should_return
...
>>> func()
False
>>> ret = func(_wait=True)
True
```

Comment: All functions in Python always return. If you don't explicitly return, functions return `None`.

Comment: Python functions don't, infact, always return. If they do return, however, then they always return a value, which unless specified, is None.

Comment: I understand that, but most of the time a function that returns `None` is equivalent to not returning anything. In this case, I need to check if it should return anything other than `None`.

Comment: Why are you concerned with whether your function should return something or not? Aren't you yourself the director of everything you write in that function?

Comment: The function in question pulls it's return values from a network socket. If the return value is not going to get used, I don't want to waste the resources fetching the result.

Comment: If you happen to feel like doing frame inspection and bytecode reading, you could see if the value is used in a function call or returns something. Bad Python style, though; Python discourages magic. As for your workaround, don't call it `__return__`; to quote [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), "Never invent such names; only use them as documented." If you want it for a specific case, specify it with some other variable name.

Comment: @Sky: It seemed to me that your question was being misunderstood, and I edited to try to make it clearer. I think it's quite interesting. Please don't hesitate to roll back my edit if you don't like it.

Comment: I don't like using leading underscores, either. Indicates a class-private value, and with the double underscore name mangling may cause you trouble if you deal with it in the wrong way. Perhaps `need_result` or `wait` (I think I prefer the last one)?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - yeah, I wasn't sure what else to call it though. It's different now.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's much clearer now, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - the function in question is also taking some other arbitrary arguments, so I wanted to use one that would not be reasonably submitted otherwise.

Comment: I know this is an ancient thread, but for posterity @Skye is asking for a Pythonic equivalent to Perl's [`wantarray`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very second line of the body of `import this` says it all: "explicit is better than implicit". In this case, if you provide an optional argument, the code will be more obvious (and thus easier to understand), simpler, faster and safer. Keep it as a separate argument with a name like `wait`.

While with difficulty you could implement it magically, it would be nasty code, prone to breaking in new versions of Python and not obvious. Avoid that route; there lieth the path unto madness.

Answer (score 3):

All functions return a value when they complete.

If you're asking if they should return at all, then you are actually asking about [The Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Comment: I understand that any function would return a value, I am more asking whether it is possible to determine if a function should return a _meaningful_ value.

Comment: What do you mean by "meaningful"?  This, is still the same halting problem.

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to return an object with a `__del__` method that relies on the garbage collector removing the unused value some time in the future. 
Note that it won't happen immediately; it might not even happen at all :)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider returning a future, or 'promise'. That is, return another function that, when executed, performs the necessary work to actually determine the result.  I seem to be thinking that you want lazy evaluation, which is "evaluate only what you need" (more or less), rather than your question, which confusingly asks: "Evaluate only if it returns a value, which might be needed".

Answer (score 0):

i have some code that kinda works using [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module, but it might be prone to break like others mention.

> inspect.stack()[1].frame.f_code.co_names[-1]

will be holding the function name when user didn't assign return value to anything, when user assign to var with name XXX, this var will hold XXX. Code comparing this vs the function name to decide whether user assign the return value to any var

```
import inspect
def func():
  tmp = inspect.stack()[1].frame.f_code.co_names[-1]
  should_return = tmp != 'func'
  print("execute") # execute something
  
  # if should_return False, end here without fetching result
  
  if should_return:
    print("fetching result, user assign to {}".format(tmp))
    # fetching result and return the result here



>>> func()
execute
>>>
>>> xxx=func()
execute
fetching result, user assign to xxx
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

All functions in Python always return. If you don't explicitly return, functions return None.

===========

def func():
    while True:
        pass

This function does not return.

There is no way of determining if an arbitrary function will return. If you can, you have solved the Turing problem.