# How to tell if a function will be returning a value to a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So to give as an *example*, imagine a function that computes a value and will either return the value to the variable or print it if it will not be stored into a variable such as:

```
def add(a, b):
    c = a+b
    if called: return c    ## Put the value into "answer" below
    else: print "Your answer is: ", str(c)    ## just print it

answer = add(10, 15)
print answer
## Should print 25

add(10, 20)
## Should print """Your answer is 30"""
```

I want to use this in various functions such as a UI or a generator but can't find a way to implement a Boolean statement to determine this.

I Googled this, and the only thing i found close was determining if the function was called or recursed(?). I just want the function to know if it should return the value to the variable or simply print it. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not provide the function a third boolean argument? A function only executes when it is called. Recursion is just a special case, but I don't think it relates to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459408/check-if-theres-something-waiting-for-the-return-value-of-a-function)

Comment: Yeah, I don't need that... I know all functions needs to be called in order to be executed, I just wanna know if the value is going somewhere. Like if i just return the value it will bluntly return the value regardless. I want a function to be more versatile that I can use for various circumstances like for a UI or generator.

Comment: This question already has an answer. See the link I gave.

Comment: I read through that a few times and can't find a viable answer. Well from what I understood. It's close, but his question seems to be either returning a value or not. His code seems to be about finding out if a value is arbitrary(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A python function has no information on whether it's return value is being assigned or ignored. So, what you want is not possible.

If you are willing to make some design changes, you could add a parameter:

```
def add(a, b, print_it):
    c = a+b
    if print_it: print "Your answer is: ", str(c)    ## just print it
    else: return c    ## Put the value into "answer" below

answer = add(10, 15)
print answer
## Will print 25

add(10, 20, true)
## Will print """Your answer is 30"""
```

Or you could define a wrapper function specifically for printing the result:

```
def add(a, b):
    c = a+b
    return c

def print_add(a, b):
    print "Your answer is: ", str(add(a, b))    ## print add's return value

answer = add(10, 15)
print answer
## Will print 25

print_add(10, 20)
## Will print """Your answer is 30"""
```

You could make the second solution more generic by passing the base function to the wrapper function:

```
def add(a, b):
    c = a+b
    return c

def sub(a, b):
    c = a-b
    return c

def print_result(fn, a, b):
    print "Your answer is: ", str(fn(a, b))    ## print function's return value

answer = add(10, 15)
print answer
## Will print 25

print_result(add, 10, 20)
## Will print """Your answer is 30"""

print_result(sub, 10, 20)
## Will print """Your answer is -10"""
```

etc, etc.

Comment: The first is a good idea, I'll have to re-do all my functions though but seems the easiest way. The second I thought about but the functions are much bigger and duplicating it would be kinda heavy lol.
But what if it's a generator and I wanna know how many variables to return back? etc

Comment: You mean "how many variables to return back" or "how many arguments to pass"? I don't understand the first: a function returns one thing, not many (although it could be a complex object or array).

Comment: First one... its a generator, you know what that is? It will yield instead or return.

Comment: In that case, the first solution remains valid, and the second solution would have the body of the wrapper function iterate through the generator returned by the base function and print. Or you could make the wrapper also a generator which iterates through the base generator, prints and yields inside the loop. It all depends what you want to do...